# PHP - 8.1 upgrade and packages in conflict requirements

Tags: php, package, composer-php

In my PHP project I am updating some composer packages as I upgraded the **PHP** to `version 8.1`

I have some Symfony packages that I am updating..

```
"symfony/console": "^6.0",
"symfony/lock": "^6.0",
"symfony/process": "^6.0" ..
```

I have problem with specific library that causes conflict during `composer install` and it's **[codeception/codeception](https://packagist.org/packages/codeception/codeception#4.1.31)**.
In my *`composer.json`*  it's  `"codeception/codeception": "^4.1"` which should be fine, but:

> Problem 1
> - codeception/codeception 4.1.9 requires symfony/console >=2.7 <6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev..] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> - codeception/codeception 4.1.31 requires symfony/console >=2.7 <6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev, 4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev..

Can you please help with this? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Codeception/module-symfony/issues/152

Answer (score -1):

They don't support symfony 6 at the moment

[image]